# Si los gatos gatean, ¿los perros...?

Tags: selección-de-palabras

El caminar de los gatos se llama, si no me equivoco, *gatear*.

¿Cómo se llamaría entonces el caminar que tienen los perros?

Comment: Es obligatorio aquí citar el muy buen Sr. Chikilicuatre: **¡Perrea, perrea!** :-)

Comment: Según la RAE cuando algo o alguien sube un tronco usando las cuatro extremidades se dice que gatea, pero el andar de los gatos no se denomina gateo. Creo que la intención de la pregunta era generar comentarios jocosos como el de @guifa :-) XD

Comment: Realmente queria saber como denominar el andar de los perros, sin que sonara como un gato :) En serio!

Answer (score 3):

Como ya se ha dicho antes, la pregunta parte de una premisa equivocada. La palabra *[gatear](http://dle.rae.es/?id=J0GaP9q)* significa:

> 1. intr. Andar a gatas.
> 2. intr. Trepar como los gatos, y especialmente subir por un tronco o astil valiéndose de los brazos y piernas.

Y *[a gatas](http://dle.rae.es/?id=J0DlL8w)* significa:

> 1. loc. adv. Dicho de ponerse o andar una persona: Con pies y manos en el suelo, como los gatos y demás cuadrúpedos.

Es decir, se dice "a gatas" como se podría haber dicho "a perras" o "a yeguas" (el porqué de esta expresión podría ser una buena pregunta), dado que la expresión solo se fija en la posición de "a cuatro patas".

Sin embargo, la segunda acepción de "gatear" (que no conocía) sí que expresa un símil de un movimiento humano (en este caso, trepar) con los movimientos de un gato. Es decir, que el verbo se fija en un movimiento felino muy característico. No existe como tal en el DRAE, pero aquí en Andalucía usamos el verbo "perrear" con la acepción de "estar sin ganas de hacer nada, y menos de moverse", como imitando a un perro tranquilo que está tumbado junto a la chimenea la mar de a gusto y que no se mueve de ahí ni aunque lo echen. También tenemos expresiones como "qué perrera tengo" para indicar que tienes [flojera](http://dle.rae.es/?id=I6M0eyb) e incluso "perreritis" como "[flojeritis](http://dle.rae.es/?id=I6P1zSo)" (esta última jamás habría dicho que fuese a estar en el diccionario). El origen de todas estas expresiones posiblemente venga de la expresión "hacer un tiempo [de perros](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SihVF3L)", dado que esos días lo único que apetece es estar tirado en el sofá con una manta viendo una peli.

Comment: ¡Fantástica recolección de _palabrejas_! :)

Answer (score 2):

En Colombia no usamos la palabra **gatear** para designar el movimiento o desplazamiento de un gato.  Esta palabra la usamos en dos contextos:

1. Para designar el primer desplazamiento que hacemos los humanos
   neonatos antes de caminar.  Desplazandonos sobre manos y rodillas, 
   como un cuadrupedo,  popularmente se denomina a este movimiento
   **gatear**.
2. Para designar un desplazamiento sigiloso.

El desplazamiento de los gatos lo designamos con las mismas palabras que designamos el movimiento de otros cuadrupedos: correr, caminar.

Comment: Realmente esas palabras se puede aplicar sin ningun problema a los seres de 2 piernas... Yo busco una palabra que se use exclusivamente para los cuadrupedos (o al menos a los perros, ya que "galopar" tampoco creo que sirviera)

Comment: @Dbugger entonces deberías reformular tu pregunta: en primer lugar, "el caminar de los gatos se llama gatear" no es verdad, y en segundo lugar, al caminar de los perros no se lo llama de ninguna manera porque los perros no tienen una forma característica de caminar como sí lo tienen los gatos. Si lo que quieres saber es cómo se llama la acción de "caminar a cuatro patas" referida a los animales (considerando que "gatear" solo aplica a las personas), eso es lo que deberías preguntar. Tal y como está redactada tu pregunta, dudo que obtengas una respuesta a lo que buscas.

Comment: Yo nunca he escuchado a nadie decir: mi gato gatea... O los gatos gatean. Puede que la expresión venga del andar del gato, porque tiene su aquel. Pero al menos en España, perros, gatos, caballos, patos, ornitorrincos, tortugas, zarigurllas o lo que Dios quiera que camine a cuatro patas... Caminan, corren, trotan,... Pero ninguno gatea.