# Si en una cuchara tenemos cucharadas, ¿qué tenemos en un tenedor?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, sustantivos

Ayer le estaba dando de comer a una hija cuando le fui a decir:

> Va, cómete lo que hay en este tenedor y ya estamos.

Normalmente lo que come es sopa, por lo que digo:

> Va, cómete esta **cucharada** y ya estamos.

Sin embargo, esta vez eran judías verdes y lo comía con tenedor. Me quedé pensativo y me di cuenta de que no, no se me ocurría ninguna palabra para designar la porción que cabe en un tenedor, a diferencia de [*cucharada*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BXXaLSO) que es *Porción que cabe en una cuchara*.

Veo que a Fundéu [le preguntaron en Twitter](https://twitter.com/fundeu/status/4580285530243072) y [respondió](http://www.twitlonger.com/show/70k341):

> RT @4Colors: Hola! Dudo: cuchara = cucharada. Tenedor = ¿tenedorada o también cucharada? / Buena pregunta. «Cucharada» es la porción que cabe en una cuchara, según el Diccionario; de ahí la expresión: «Tomar una cucharada» es 'tomar la porción que cabe en una cuchara'. Con un tenedor parece que no existe; puede ser debido a que con el tenedor se pincha y el tamaño de la porción puede variar. Un saludo

Pero así y todo, ¿se os ocurre algún término, ya sea en España o en Hispanoamérica, que pueda usarse para designar este concepto?

Comment: Cucharada es una **unidad de medida** que se relaciona con la cantidad de algo que cabe en una cuchara.  En un tenedor ensartamos **un pedazo** de algo pero no genera una cantidad **estándar**. Es un argumento parecido a "un vaso de agua" o "un vaso con agua" donde el primero es una unidad de medida y el otro no.

Comment: No lo pongo como respuesta porque no creo que esta pregunta la tenga, pero en el caso de darle de comer a tu hija con un tenedor, la última frase sería algo como **Va, comete este último pedazo/pedacito/bocado y ya estamos**

Comment: Yo a veces uso cucharada para el tenedor también, al final es una medida y aunque no esté en una cuchara puede ser una cucharada.

Comment: _Cucharada_ looks natural for using the fork like a scoop unless fedorqui is teaching his daughter that this is impolite.

Comment: @mdewey well, she is only two, so having her use the fork anyway is the main goal :) I had never thought on using _cucharada_ for anything beyond using the _cuchara_, but it makes sense.

Comment: Yo soy de los que secunda las observaciones de @DGaleano. Lo único que se me ocurre es "pinchazo" (o incluso "pinchado"), aludiendo a la _acción y efecto_ de usar de tal manera el tenedor en lugar de a la porción (o tamaño de la misma) _pinchada_ en el mismo. Supongo que manejando un cuchillo diríamos "otro _corte_ más", en lugar de aludir al tamaño de la porción cortada. Revisando otros verbos que yo creía sinónimos (como trinchar o picotear) no encuentro ninguno que se adapte mejor que _pinchar_. Pero ninguno diríamos "otro _pichazo/pinchado/picotazo_ más" en lugar de "otro **trocito** más".

Comment: Definitivamente, *bocado*. // No se da de comer a un niño pequeño con tenedor.  Si está tan pequeño que no puede agarrar la comida él mismo con la mano o con cubierto, entonces le estás dando de comer con *cuchara*.

Comment: Aunque no exista en los diccionarios no veo por qué no se podría decir "tenedorada", lo peor de esa palabra es que es rara de pronunciar. Existe *horquillada* y una horquilla no es muy distinta de un tenedor.

Comment: No sé si te servirá, pero en Aragón (España) se dice "ganchada", como en "¿me das una ganchadica?". Ignoro si procede del aragonés o simplemente es la forma que tomó el castellano, pero es la que se usa.

Comment: @blonfu your suggestion of _horquillada_ looks a good one, why not post it as an answer?

Comment: 'Si en una cuchara tenemos cucharadas, ¿qué tenemos en un tenedor?' no es un trabalenguas tan malo...

Comment: Me recuerda a https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/15766/si-los-gatos-gatean-los-perros

Comment: Quizá desde el lenguaje se contempla solo el uso del tenedor para pinchar, y no para porciones. Un saludo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Acabo de leer un artículo de un periódico español titulado: [@RAEinforma te informa, pero no hace los deberes](https://elpais.com/cultura/2019/03/08/actualidad/1552043265_456050.html) y en él se incluye la siguiente cita a una consulta que es relevante para esta pregunta:

> "En referencia a la porción de alimento que se toma con el tenedor, se usa normalmente el término ‘**pinchada**’, a menudo se usa la forma diminutiva ‘**pinchadita**’; el derivado ‘tenedorada’ se usa muy raramente".

El artículo no enlaza a esta consulta de Twitter, así que he tenido que buscarla, y creo que es esta: ["Como seria la palabra con el significado de "porción recogida en un tenedor"](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/948888921068404736), ya que la respuesta a la consulta es la misma que se cita arriba.

Aparte, en Twitter para @RAEConsultas tenemos la consulta [¿si para cuchara es cucharada cómo sería el equivalente para tenedor?](https://twitter.com/raeinforma/status/950271352979841025?lang=en) donde aprendemos:

> Se podría usar «tenedorada» como derivado análogo a «cucharada», aunque apenas se documenta en el uso. También serían válidas las voces generales «pinchada» o «bocado».

Veo que los términos "pinchada" y "pinchadita" ya estaban sugeridos en los comentarios pero nadie había aportado ninguna referencia sobre la validez de su uso. De igual manera, la pregunta enlaza al Twitter de Fundeu, pero creo que no se había mencionada antes al Twitter de la RAE, donde hemos encontrado una pregunta igual a la que tenemos aquí.

Por tanto, la RAE valida los usos como

> Va, cómete esta **pinchada** (o *pinchadita*) y ya estamos.
>
> Va, cómete este **bocado** y ya estamos.

y por supuesto el ya mencionado "tenedorada" (que de acuerdo a la RAE se usa raramente)

> Va, cómete esta **tenedorada** y ya estamos.